# Spring boot load test database when run from cmd

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, gradle, spring-boot

I have a spring boot project that load correctly with postgres when started from Eclipse but when started by the windows command window, the test database is loaded.

When I start the application from the cmd with `java -jar happy_list-0.1.0.jar` I have this error ( I removed part of the stacktrace) :

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Driver for test database
>   type [HSQL] is not available in the classpath
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver

I don't have any test or configuration for tests. It must be some auto-configuration done by Spring boot, but I don't understand why it behave differently when run from eclipse or windows cmd.

PersistentContext :

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "happy_listing" })
public class PersistentContext {

}
```

App.java :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "happy_listing" })
@Import({ PersistentContext.class })
public class App {

    @Configuration
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
    static class ApplicationProperties {
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

}
```

Build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.5.RELEASE")
        classpath('se.transmode.gradle:gradle-docker:1.2')
    }
}

group = 'marcandregirard'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'docker'

jar {
    baseName = 'happy_list'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

springBoot {
  mainClass = "happy_listing.App"
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.13'
    compile 'javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-core'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-dbcp2', version: '2.1.1'
    compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.9.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager'
    compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4-1206-jdbc42'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-web'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

task buildDocker(type: Docker, dependsOn: build) {
  push = true
  applicationName = jar.baseName
  dockerfile = file('src/main/docker/Dockerfile')
  doFirst {
    copy {
      from jar
      into stageDir
    }
  }
}
```

I created the jar with the command `gradle build buildDocker` which create the jar and image to run in Docker.

Everything is working fine when started form Eclipse.

Comment: If you need any other information or there is something not correct just say so in the comments.

Comment: Also make sure that you don't have an external `application.properties` or something in the config folder next to your jar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters I would start cleaning up your dependencies instead of all separate jar files use the appropriate starters.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-dbcp2', version: '2.1.1'
    compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4-1206-jdbc42'
    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

Next it looks like you are trying to do a lot of manual configuration `@SpringBootApplication` already implies the other 3 and Spring Boot already loads the `application.properties`. Remove that

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

}
```

Remove your `PersistenceContext` class as that is already done by Spring Boot for you.

After cleaning up your classes and dependencies make sure that no old classes are left. For that execute the Gradle `clean` task. `gradle clean` should do the trick.

So when removing classes also make sure you do a `gradle clean build` instead of a plain `gradle build`.

Comment: Well thanks for the cleanup everything is still working in eclipse and it's much cleaner. The problem still persist do you need any more information ?

Comment: As mentioned in the comment check your `application.properties` and also your environment variables for properties that might trigger this behavior. Spring Boot loads `application.properties` from certain locations.

Comment: Weird, in the jar I have a class DataBaseConfig added in my config package but I don't have it in my project in eclipse, may that be the problem ?

Comment: That can be, why do you even have such a class? Spring Boot just needs configuration in an `application.properties` to configure the datasource. As I mentioned somewhere looks like you are trying to configure too much yourself.

Comment: I don't know why but my jar have some classes that does not exist in my project. I don't at which step of the build include or create but there was also a `HelloWorld` class which still does not exist...

Comment: Yeah a simple clean resolved my issue... Still wonders why recreating the jar would leave those classes in the jar. Could you edit this in your answer ?

Comment: Well when doing a build that doesn't automatically clean which leaves old classes in build dir and automatically in the jar.